# calling subcategories when categories selected in codeigniter using ajax giving error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a simple form in codeigniter website where am trying to display sub categories when categories are selected, i did the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#country').change(function() {
    var country_id = $('#country').val();
    if (country_id != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/homecontroller/fetchstate",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          country_id: country_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#state').html(data);
          $('#city').html('<option value="">Select Brand</option>');
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#state').html('<option value="">Select Category</option>');
      $('#city').html('<option value="">Select Brand</option>');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="inputEmail4">Category</label>

  <select id="country" class="form-control" name="cname" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <?php

  foreach($listcategory as $vals){
              echo '<option value="'.$vals->name.'">'.$vals->name.'</option>';
             }?>
  </select>

  <label for="inputEmail4">Brand</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="sname" id="state">
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>

  </select>
```

i have the controller and model like below:

```html
function fetchstate()
{
if($this->input->post('country_id'))
{
echo $this->excel_import_model->fetch_state($this->input->post('country_id'));

}
}
```

```html
function fetch_state($country_id)
 {
  $this->db->where('inventorycategory', $country_id);
  $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');
  $query = $this->db->get('inventorybrand');
  $output = '<option value="">Select Brand</option><option value="None">None</option>';
  foreach($query->result() as $row)
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row->name.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
  }
  return $output;
 }
```

now here the issue is when i select the category it doesnt display sub category, i get the following error:

> POST http://localhost/letsship/index.php/homecontroller/fetchstate 500 (Internal Server Error)

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message, go check the error log to find details about what went wrong.

Comment: @CBroe it doesnt show any error3

Comment: Can u share your database table